# What is generalized law of mean and what is a book that introduce that?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

What is generalized and extension law of mean/mean value theorem and what is a book that introduce that and the topics below?

I want to learn more about that before i taking that course.

That course also introduce  limit, continuity, derivative and differential of a function of one variable. Other topics include real numbers and the axiom of continuity, convergence of a sequence of real numbers; elements of point set topology; and extensions and generalizations of the law of the mean.

I had no idea what textbook of that course called advanced calculus 1 will be using...

I already try out the college bookstore website but the the course isn't there.

It can't be Larson or Gilbert text since it is considerably more rigorous and advanced than calculus 3

I guess the course textbook had all these terminology in the book index

Website: http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/math/course_syllabi/4010.html

Comment: I think any ordinary real analysis book will do; I learned from Strichartz *The Way of Analysis*. It is a bit heavy on the exposition and has a somewhat strange choice of notation. (Specifically, it doesn't use $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ for a *long* time, preferring to use $1/n$ and $1/m$ for most of the text. Annoyingly, it also exchanges their roles halfway through.) But it is very good for intuition while at the same time staying quite rigorous and reasonably focused. There are many other texts of this character, I think my current university uses Fitzpatrick *Advanced Calculus*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, Baruch. My undergraduate alma mater was Queens College of CUNY,so I feel obligated to answer in a family-sorta way.......lol

A great-and now cheap-text on single variable advanced calculus by a master teacher at MIT is Arthur Mattuck's *Introduction To Analysis.*  I was absolutely floored to learn this incredible book was reissued in a fantastically cheap paperback last year after becoming exceedingly scarce-and correspondingly expensive-in it’s original hardcover edition. Mattuck’s reissuing of the book through Createspace in a 13 dollar (!) paperback as the standard text for the 18.100A course at MIT, which he has taught there for many years, demonstrates this legendary teacher’s commitment to assisting students learn analysis who do not have the strong background and/or talent of students who can directly enter an abstract analysis course based on metric spaces. The author’s “mission statement” of the text in the Preface is quite informative and should be read by all students and teachers of mathematics. Basically, the need for such a text became clear from Mattuck’s many years of teaching analysis to students who struggled in the typical metric spaces-based analysis course. (And these were MIT students, so the usual snarky response of mathematics honors students that they just weren’t bright enough to learn analysis becomes manifestly absurd in this case…..)

For beginners, analysis should look like calculus, only much more careful. The author takes great pains to give proofs in great detail, all done by specific calculational methods at first, which slowly give way to more general arguments as theorems are established throughout the book. The Completeness property is given in terms of Cauchy convergence. The author writes beautifully and clearly, with many deep insights that are usually omitted as obvious in not only analysis courses, but calculus courses. For example, he goes into some detail on why subtracting inequalities is illegal.  He also can be wryly amusing at times. There are tons of excellent problems all with complete solutions, which will make the book incredibly useful for self-study. Mattuck has written an outstanding textbook that all students of mathematics regardless of level can learn from. It’s  an absolute gift that the book is now available so cheaply to beginning students of analysis and there’s no reason not to have a copy. I think you'll find it a perfect fit for your needs and budget-hopefully,your professor decides to use it.

The generalized law of the mean and how it it's related to the ordinary mean value theorem is discussed at some length in Mattuck and other books. Let's review with the regular MVT. Geometrically,what it means roughly is that given a planar arc between two endpoints, there is at least one point at which the tangent to the arc is parallel to the secant through its endpoints, like so: 
[image]

Now the generalized or extended MVT,which is called sometimes the Cauchy MVT since it was discovered by Cauchy. It states that if there exists functions f and g both continuous on the closed interval [a,b], and differentiable on the open interval (a, b), then there exists some c ∈ (a,b), such that (f(b) - f(a)) (g'(c)) =  (g(b) - g(a)) (f'(c)). This result is quite useful in calculus, particularly in proving results with indeterminate forms, such as L'Hopital's rule. Geometrically, what the extended MTV says is that there is some tangent to the graph of the curve $L:[a,b] \rightarrow R^{2}$ where for every $t\in[a,b]$ $t\rightarrow (f(g),g(t))$ which is parallel to the line defined by the points (f(a),g(a)) and (f(b),g(b)) like so:

[image]

However Cauchy's theorem does not claim the existence of such a tangent in all cases where (f(a),g(a)) and (f(b),g(b)) are distinct points, since it might be satisfied only for some value c with f′(c) = g′(c) = 0.

Full proofs of these results are given in any good elementary real analysis or advanced calculus book.

Hope you found this post helpful. Good luck!